# Why sync bintray with maven central?

Tags: maven, publish, bintray, maven-central

I'm building few projects and publish them to bintray. After that i can add resolver that points to my repository and use any library in that repo.

So what is the point to sync your package with maven central?

i see these reasons:

1. my package will be available in mvnrepository search. I can see usages of my package in other libraries
2. maven central is default resolver, so i don't need add any other resolvers in sbt

Are there any other reasons? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From bintray [blog](https://blog.bintray.com/2014/02/11/bintray-as-pain-free-gateway-to-maven-central/) :

> Maven Central is “hardwired” into the super-popular Maven 2. As such,
>   it is being used by many Maven users of course, but also by Ivy, and
>   even by Gradle users (those not familiar with Bintray’s ‘jcenter()’
>   repo yet).

So you need to deploy your artifact into Maven Central, but it is somehow painful so **Sync** is better option.

Comment: I think any gradle user can add resolver to bintray, no?

Comment: If deployed in `jcenter` then `jcenter()` is enough but if not, specific url required and that is tough to remember all artifacts resolver

Comment: [performance wise](https://www.jfrog.com/knowledge-base/why-should-i-use-jcenter-over-maven-central/) bintray is quite dominating but we also need to consider those developer who is not familiar with bintray or jcenter